# Angular 5: Unit testing fail on Firefox

Tags: angular, unit-testing, firefox

I write test with Karma and Jasmine for Angular 5 component. Tests are running on Chrome and Firefox (karma-chrome-launcher v2.1.1 and karma-firefox-launcher v1.1.0)

On Chrome all tests are successfully but for Firefox there is a strange error: `[object ErrorEvent] thrown`

```
Firefox 58.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.0) Component: Login should redirect if user click Forgot password button FAILED
        [object ErrorEvent] thrown
Firefox 58.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.0): Executed 33 of 43 (1 FAILED) (skipped 6) (0 secs / 10.761 secs)
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 33 of 43 (skipped 6) SUCCESS (0 secs / 5.868 secs)
Firefox 58.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.0) Component: Login should redirect if user click Forgot password button FAILED
        [object ErrorEvent] thrown
Firefox 58.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.0): Executed 37 of 43 (1 FAILED) (skipped 6) (13.172 secs / 12.945 secs)
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 37 of 43 (skipped 6) SUCCESS (7.108 secs / 6.964 secs)
```

Test *should redirect if user click Forgot password button*:

```
  it('should redirect if user click Forgot password button', inject([UserService], (userService: UserService) => {
    // GIVEN
    spyOn(userService, 'goToLogin');

    // WHEN
    component.goToForgotPassword();

    // THEN
    expect(userService.goToLogin).toHaveBeenCalledWith(Constants.AUTH_PAGES.FORGOT_PASSWORD);
  }));
```

If I run this test individually then everything works normally.

The problems started when I include one test with `fakeAsync`. If I remove this test then everything works normally.

Had someone similar problems or do I do something wrong?
Thanks